# Viscous fluid boundary condition

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Consider an incompressible viscous ﬂuid of kinematic viscosity
$ν$ , dynamic viscosity
$µ$
and density
$ρ$ . A viscous boundary layer is located over a solid surface at $y = 0$ and $x > 0$. The ﬂow in the boundary layer must match with the constant inviscid bulk velocity $U$. The steady two-dimensional boundary-layer equations are $$\frac{∂ u}{ ∂ x} + \frac{∂ v}{ ∂ y} = 0$$
$$ρ
\bigg( u
\frac{∂ u }{∂ x}
+v
\frac{∂ u }{∂ y} \bigg)=
µ \frac{∂ ^2u }{∂ y^2}$$ where $u(x,y)$ is the horizontal velocity and $v(x,y)$ the vertical velocity.

(i) State the boundary conditions on $u$ and $v$ along $y = 0$ and $x > 0$.

(ii) State the far-ﬁeld condition on $u$ as $y→∞$.

---

It says "The ﬂow in the boundary layer must match with the constant inviscid bulk velocity $U$" so does this mean that the resultant of the $u$ and $v$ velocity components should be equal to $U$?

Then for (i) $u(x,y=0)=v(x,y=0)=U/\sqrt2$?

For (ii), is the far field condition just $u \rightarrow 0$ as $y \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: I think the far field condition is $u\rightarrow U$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

'It says "The ﬂow in the boundary layer must match with the constant inviscid bulk velocity U'

It means that **as you approach the boundary** from within the boundary layer, the velocity must approach the bulk velocity U.  It does NOT mean that the velocity within the boundary layer is constant.